# HTML in Mootools' Element constructor?

Tags: constructor, mootools

I'm currently using the Mootools Element constructor method to dynamically add a new row into a table.

```
function newPermission(somedata) {
    var newUserPerm = new Element('tr', {
        'html': '<td>foo</td><td>bar</td>'
    });
    newUserPerm.inject('permissions_table');
}
```

However, upon checking the resulting code, the following HTML string gets added to the table:

```
<tr>foobar</tr>
```

I'm sure there's some way to send the HTML tags as well, but I can't find much on it here, except one other question, in which the user had an outdated ver. of Mootools...

Comment: Or you can try using HtmlTable class instead - http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/HtmlTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this has been fixed in mootools 1.3 beta and i think only affects tables (otherwise html setters via element constructors are fine) - in the mean while, do not set the html through the element constructor but set the it after you create the TR:

```
var tr = new Element('tr').inject(document.id("foo").getElement("tbody"), "top");
tr.set("html", '<td>foo</td><td>bar</td>');
```

here it is working as you had it in 1.3: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/ALsBK/

and here it is breaking in 1.2.4: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/ALsBK/1/

and working in 1.2.4: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/ALsBK/2/